# ElasticSearch with Play 2 configuration

Tags: frameworks, playframework, playframework-2.0, elasticsearch

I am trying to use the ElasticSearch module (https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch) with my Play 2 application.  In the readme, it says I should add the following to my application.conf:

```
    ## define local mode or not
elasticsearch.local=false

## list clients
elasticsearch.client="192.168.0.46:9300"
# ex : elasticsearch.client="192.168.0.46:9300,192.168.0.47:9300"
```

What is local mode?  What is my client URL supposed to be?  I can not find any information on what these options should be.   With my current options, I get a NoNodeAvailableException.

Some people suggest:

```
elasticsearch.local=false elasticsearch.client=mynode1:9200,mynode2:9200
```

But what is mynode1 and mynode2?  It doesn't work with my application.  Can anyone help?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is local mode?

> If elaticsearch.local=true, a elasticsearch node is started in your application ( embedded )

What is my client URL supposed to be?

> It's your host:port, but the port is the tcp transport define on your elasticsearch node.
>    By default, the port start on 9300 ( http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/transport.html )

I can not find any information on what these options should be. With my current options, I get a NoNodeAvailableException.

> I think you have a problem on port number.

Answer (score 0):

mynode1 and mynode2 are elasticsearch nodes.

Do you have any Elasticsearch node running?
On which IP address?

Can you try to connect on these nodes using curl, for example:

```
curl localhost:9200
```

Or

```
curl YOURIPADDRESS:9200
```

If one of this is successful, then configure your play app using YOURIPADDRESS:9300 as Nicolas Boire wrote before.
If no one is successful, check that you have installed Elasticsearch and launched it before.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem, be sure that you respect the version requirements written in the table : https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch

At the beginning, I set up the latest version of the plugin `0.8.1` but my ElasticSearch version was `1.0.2`.
By starting ES with version `0.9.13`, it worked.